# How can I disable opening of panes when hovering over them in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, hover

I use Netbeans 7.0.1. The vertical tabs (Favorites, Projects, Files, etc) open when hovering over them for a second. How can I disable this and make sure they only open when clicked?

Comment: Indeed annoying... did somthing change with the newer versions of NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting that I know of to accomplish this.  The only way you could possibly accomplish this is by hacking the source code yourself.  Also, you could file an [RFE (Request for Enhancement)](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html).